# Github actions err: bash: line 3: npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, git, npm, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to deploy a nodejs app from github to a remote ubuntu server via ssh. Here is my main.yml:

```
name: Node Github CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Node Js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
       
    - name: SSH and deploy node app
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master        
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SERVER_KEY }}
        script: |
          service myservice stop
          cd leancrm-backend
          git pull git://myuser@github.com/mycmp/myapp-backend.git master
          npm install
          service myservice start
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
======CMD======
service myservice stop
cd myapp-backend
git pull git://myuser@github.com/mycmp/myapp-backend.git master
npm install
service myservice start

======END======
err: fatal: Unable to look up myuser@github.com (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
err: bash: line 3: npm: command not found
==============================================
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 26):

Since you are connected to your server I assume you already have the repo there, so you only need to execute git pull.

Also you should add these lines at the beginning of the script:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

My yml file looks like these at the end:

```
script: |
  git pull
  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
  source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh                
  npm install
  npm run start_server
```

Comment: This really helps thank you for the solution

Comment: This did the trick. I updated to nvm as well and npm didn't work as I removed it from usr local bin folder

Comment: I was able to run NPM when I logged in to the server via SSH, but Github kept failing. This did the trick to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Reason:

I use nvm for the server node environment, and nvm will not install the node environment in the /usr/local/bin/ directory, so that sudo can't find the corresponding instructions, and finally create a soft connection to solve

```
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npm" "/usr/local/bin/npm" 

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/pm2" "/usr/local/bin/pm2"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/yarn" "/usr/local/bin/yarn"
```

you can test "sudo npm -v"

Comment: I had an issue and this solved it. I couldn't execute any commands like npm/pm2 via github actions. By linking them it now works unlike other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer your answer solved my problem

Comment: I'm using Volta and that solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation this really helped

Answer (score 3):

Your first step

```
name: Node Js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
```

sets up Node.js on the GitHub build runner. Your second step however...

```
 name: SSH and deploy node app
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master        
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SERVER_KEY }}
        script: |
          service myservice stop
          cd leancrm-backend
          git pull git://myuser@github.com/mycmp/myapp-backend.git master
          npm install
          service myservice start
```

... SSHs to your server and then runs script instructions *there*. You're also attempting to check out your source code repo there.

What you probably wanna do is check out your repo on the GitHub build runner...

```
- name: Checkout repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

.. then run `npm install` there, then `scp` the output to your server, and finally `ssh` to that machine and restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did install **npm** on your remote ubuntu.
**npm** also needs to be installed on the remote server for the deployment.