# Github Actions Configuration issues

Tags: github-actions

I have configured github actions workflow for some of my servers. My workflow just do one specific command and its **`npm run prod`**. I have three servers and all of them does this all together by once. But the problem is that some servers can run the **`npm run prod`** and others can't even find **npm**. I have other workflow running on other different servers but nothing like this ever happened.

This server contains a laravel application, runs supervisor on the background. So what should i do now?

Comment: Did you use `actions/setup-node@v1` in the same job?

Comment: No i didn't setup the node@v1 job

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam, Please add below code snippet after your checkout step.
```yaml
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "10.16.0"
```

Comment: @Sam-Sundar could you be more specific? i cant add this **actions/setup-node@v2** as i have already used appleboy/ssh-action@master for ssh to the server, how could i add this action?

Comment: @MD Nasirul Islam, are you using self-hosted runners ?

Comment: @Sam-Sundar no i am not using self hosted i'm using the github

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam It would be helpful, if you post your workflow yml file here

Comment: @Sahit 
Could you please verify my workflow. 
name: Testing Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-npm-on-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run npm on server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: 1.2.3.4
          username: ubuntu
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd /var/www/html/my-node-app/
            npm run prod

Comment: Whenever i run this workflow my server tells me that **npm not found**

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam if node js exists on your server, it works. Probably node js is not installed on your VM. For avoiding errors, u can include `sudo dnf module install -y nodejs:12` [CentOS, rhel] in the script where you are running `npm`.   For ubuntu `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: @Sahit yes you are right, my server got some issues with npm and node. The thing was that i setup node using nvm so the node and npm was installed using normal user but root was not able to find it because of the installation directory. To prevent this error i had to create a symlink to /usr/bin/node & /usr/bin/npm from the nvm location and it worked as expected thanks for the help man. Really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who helped and tried to help, well the problem was with my npm and node. NPM & Node was installed using NVM on the server so whenever **github actions** tried to run the `npm run prod` on the server it was trying `sudo npm run prod` instead of `npm run prod` well using the `root` permission. When i tried running `sudo node -v` it gave me error but `npm -v` gave me output so i checked the directories for `node` & `npm` they were installed on the `.nvm` directory as they were installed using `nvm` so for the solution i created a symlink on the server pointing the `node` & `npm` location to `/usr/bin/node` & `/usr/bin/npm` and it worked after that.
these are the commands

```sh
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node"

sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npm" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
```

And the stackoverflow question thread for the solution [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67923563/10308630)